# How do I find a secant line?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to learn how to approximate a nonlinear function by a linear function when I stumbled upon the problem; how to find the best secant line. I tried to figure out how but whenever I would try I would get some super long equation that I can't understand. Can somebody explain how to find the best secant line in a simple way?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange.com.  It may help if you clarify some context on what background you have.  The answer for someone who has seen some calculus will be different for someone who hasn't, for example.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "the best secant line" to be the closest approximation to the nonlinear function by a linear function, on some finite interval.   Best has to be defined by some metric of closeness.  A typical approach for the best $L^\infty$ norm (minimizing the maximum absolute error) would require finding three points in the interval where the "error" at these arguments is of equal absolute value and alternates in sign.  See [Remez exchange algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm) for more details.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "best" secant line. Given two secant lines, in what way do you judge one to be "better" than the other? There is one very well-known way of doing this, but the resulting best line is not in general a "secant" line anymore.